# Searching posts and/or pages with woocomerce search function

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I'm trying to make the search function look for post and/or pages on my website and not only products.

It seems that woocommerce is adding "`&post_type=product`" at the back of the url whenever i search something. and thus, only products show up. if i removed the added extension on the URL, then posts and pages will show up.

how do i remove the extension by default when i search?

i tried using relevanssi with posts and pages indexed but i still have the same problem.

anyway, i'm using `get_search_form();` to display the search bar.
any idea how do i get it to search for posts and pages?

*wordpress 3.9, woocommerce with mystile template.*

UPDATE:

urls:

> with extension:  (only 2 products and no posts)
>   http://edleuro.com/new/?s=wood+grains&post_type=product
>
> without extension: (2 products with post)
>   http://edleuro.com/new/?s=wood+grains